# Changes in timezones BigQuery scheduled query

Tags: google-bigquery

We recently moved from standard time to DST.
All of our scheduled queries are according to our local timezone (UTC+2), ever since the time changed it automatically changed to UTC+3 and all scheduled processes just started running one hour later than we defined. 
Eve if I try to change it, I define the job for 08:00 AM, press update and it changes to 09:00 AM by itself.
This is really frustrating. 
Any one knows this issue? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already a [bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/152711968) on the issue tracker about it. I will let you know if there will be any updates.

What you can think about for now, is [schedule jobs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml#the_schedule_format) with `cron.yaml` using `timezone` parameter.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, I hope it will be fixed soon.